# How to train Naive Bayes classifier in nltk on different corpus?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I want to use textblob for sentiment analysis for financial news. But when using
`TextBlob("news text", analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer()))`.

I am very new to python, but according to some references, the above line uses a pretrained Naive Bayes Classifier trained on movie reviews corpus. There are many other corpus available at http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/. I feel may be movie reviews corpus may not be suitable for analyzing sentiment of financial news. Some words may have different polarity and weightage when used in different context. If I want to use Reuters corpus, what should I do? Is there any pretrained model already available or some other way I can use it as the above one uses movie reviews corpus?

If no, how do I train one and how much time does it take? I am new to python and have no idea how much time/memory/processing power will it take.

Comment: Training a NaiveBayes classifier is not really difficult but cleaning your text and preparing it for training is a bit tricky. This is a nice introduction here that I believe you can follow: [naive-bayes-classifier-nltk-tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/naive-bayes-classifier-nltk-tutorial)